# How to clean the city and state(both full and abbreviation) using R

Tags: r, replace, lookup

I have a list of uncleaned city and state from "Location" in twitter, for example:

```
location <- c("the Great Lake State", "PA", "Harrisburg, Pennsylvania",
              "Pennsylvania", "MI", "Detroit,MI")
```

How to clean the data to make a clean list of two columns with city and state?

[image: desired output]

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
splitted_list <- strsplit(location,",")
wide_matrix   <- sapply(splitted_list,function(x) c(rep(NA,length(x)==1),x))
res <- setNames(data.frame(t(wide_matrix),stringsAsFactors = FALSE),c("city","state"))
res
#         city                state
# 1       <NA> the Great Lake State
# 2       <NA>                   PA
# 3 Harrisburg         Pennsylvania
# 4       <NA>         Pennsylvania
# 5       <NA>                   MI
# 6    Detroit                   MI
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data (`location`) is already part of a data.frame which you want to clean up, then `tidyr::separate` can be suitable option.

```
location <- c("the Great Lake State", "PA", "Harrisburg, Pennsylvania",
              "Pennsylvania", "MI", "Detroit,MI")


library(tidyverse)

as.data.frame(location) %>% # I created a data.frame, which is not needed in actual data 
  tidyr::separate(location, c("City", "State"), sep=",", fill="left")

#         City                State
# 1       <NA> the Great Lake State
# 2       <NA>                   PA
# 3 Harrisburg         Pennsylvania
# 4       <NA>         Pennsylvania
# 5       <NA>                   MI
# 6    Detroit                   MI
```

Comment: @YvonneDong Did this worked for you? You can accept an answer by clicking on `Tick` symbol at left of the answer box.